# Unable to start python process from java in Spring Boot

Tags: java, python, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to schedule a task to start a python script. For some reason when the scheduled task executes, the script doesn't run (throws error).

Following is the code for the task:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
public void reportCurrentTime() throws IOException {
    logger.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    String[] commandToExecute = new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "python test.py"};
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToExecute);
    BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String errorResult = error.readLine();
    String inputResult = input.readLine();
    logger.info("Err-Result: " + errorResult);
    logger.info("In-Result: " + inputResult);
}
```

I get the following output on the console:

```
2019-01-17 23:45:11.220  INFO 11032 --- [   scheduling-1] c.z.eta.scheduler.UpdateFileScheduler    : The time is now 23:45:11
2019-01-17 23:45:11.379  INFO 11032 --- [   scheduling-1] c.z.eta.scheduler.UpdateFileScheduler    : Err-Result: python: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2019-01-17 23:45:11.379  INFO 11032 --- [   scheduling-1] c.z.eta.scheduler.UpdateFileScheduler    : In-Result: null
```

I have to note that `test.py` is in the same directory as the `UpdateFileScheduler` class.

Also, i tried running the `dir` command, but for some reason the output is like this:

```
2019-01-17 23:47:28.613  INFO 3484 --- [   scheduling-1] c.z.eta.scheduler.UpdateFileScheduler    : The time is now 23:47:28
2019-01-17 23:47:28.657  INFO 3484 --- [   scheduling-1] c.z.eta.scheduler.UpdateFileScheduler    : Err-Result: null
2019-01-17 23:47:28.657  INFO 3484 --- [   scheduling-1] c.z.eta.scheduler.UpdateFileScheduler    : In-Result:  Volume in drive C has no label.
```

I am not sure what the working directory of the process is, and why it doesn't run the script.

Any ideas?

Edit: when I specify the absolute path in the `commandToExecute`, it works just fine. How do I figure out where the process is started?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem is that the process is started in the root of the project directory.
In my case it's `eta`, if you look through the logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the maven / gradle standards there should never be a non-java file in the same folder as the java files. The java package structure would be in src/main/java/* and all non-java files would be in src/main/resources/*

This python script would likely be entirely external to the project and would be placed outside of the /src structure altogether as you have discovered.

EDIT: Additionally I would argue that you should be using absolute paths regardless of what java sets as the working directory - anything else is likely a cause for a security risk in any enterprise project.